# NodeJs - optimization multiple if

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Here is my code :

```
Search.prototype.makeQuery = function (data) {
    let result = {};
    if (data.orderId) {
        result["order_id"] = data.orderId;
    }
    if (data.userMobileNumber) {
        result["user.Number"] = {$regex : data.userMobileNumber}
    }
    if (data.userFullName) {
        result["user.Name"] = {$regex: data.userFullName}
    }
    return result;
};
```

All I want is finding better way to optimize my code and reduce `if` condition in my code. Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you think about switch / case : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *avoid* the typing of `if` when you wrap it into a function and the typing of `data` with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
The *advantage* of wrapping the `if` in this case into a function is that you can simply test it, it is reusable and easy to read

## Code

```
Search.prototype.makeQuery = function (data) {
    let result = {}
    let {orderId, userMobileNumber, userFullName} = data
    setObjectValue(orderId, result, "order_id", orderId)
    setObjectValue(userMobileNumber, result, "user.Number", {$regex : userMobileNumber})
    setObjectValue(userFullName, result, "user.Name", {$regex: userFullName})
    return result;
}

function setObjectValue(condition, object, key, value) {
    if(condition) {
        object[key] = value
    }
}
```

## Working Example

```js
function makeQuery (data) {
    let result = {}
    let {orderId, userMobileNumber, userFullName} = data
    setObjectValue(orderId, result, "order_id", orderId)
    setObjectValue(userMobileNumber, result, "user.Number", {$regex : userMobileNumber})
    setObjectValue(userFullName, result, "user.Name", {$regex: userFullName})
    return result;
}

function setObjectValue(condition, object, key, value) {
    if(condition) {
        object[key] = value
    }
}

let data = {
    orderId: 1,
    userMobileNumber: "016875447895",
    userFullName: "John Doe"
}

let query = makeQuery(data)

console.log(query)
```

Comment: Nice, simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way:

```
Search.prototype.makeQuery = function (data) {
    let result = {};    
    data.orderId && (result["order_id"] = data.orderId);
    data.userMobileNumber && (result["user.Number"] = {$regex : data.userMobileNumber});
    data.userFullName && (result["user.Name"] = {$regex: data.userFullName});
    return result;
};
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you have many fields or you want to modify them, you would create a map. Right now, your code works and my solution is overkill but it may be useful in the future:

```js
const interestingData = new Map()
    //I tried to imitate your values. 
    // Use whatever function you want here as a callback. 
    // value is the value you request, the callback must return the value you want to set.
interestingData.set("order_id", value => value)
interestingData.set("user.Number", value => ({ $regevalue: value }))
interestingData.set("user.Name", value => ({ $regevalue: value }))

//Tgis is a Factory in case you need several search.
const makeSearch = fields => data => {
    let result = {}
    fields.forEach((callBack, field) => {
        if (data[field])
            result[field] = callBack(data[field])
    })
    return result
}

//Creating a searching function
const myResearch = makeSearch(interestingData)

//Fake examples
const data1 = {
    order_id: 'ertyui',
    "user.Number": "ertyuio",
    "user.Name": "ertyuio",
    azerr: 123456
}

const data2 = {
    order_id: 'ertyui',
    "user.Number": "ertyuio",

}

console.log(myResearch(data1))
console.log(myResearch(data2))
```

It is not *simpler* but it is more **extensible**, and when you have many parameters, it is going to be much **faster** on a big scale. It is also reusable. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you'd consider this as code optimization, but you can get rid of the `if` statements using `Object.assign`:

```
Search.prototype.makeQuery = function (data) {
  return Object.assign({},
      data.orderId && { order_id: data.orderId },
      data.userMobileNumber && {
        'user.Number': { $regex : data.userMobileNumber },
      },
      data.userFullName && {
        'user.Name': { $regex : data.userFullName },
      },
    )
};
```

If you can use newer JS features (with a transpiler or otherwise), you could use `Object rest/spread` for a slightly more concise syntax:

```
Search.prototype.makeQuery = (data) => ({
  ...data.orderId && { order_id: data.orderId },
  ...data.userMobileNumber && {
    'user.Number': { $regex : data.userMobileNumber },
  },
  ...data.userFullName && {
     user.Name': { $regex : data.userFullName },
  },
});
```

Edit 1: note that all these are pure functions, no mutations are taking place whatsoever